# In the gitlab-runner, How can I keep the build/?

Tags: gitlab-ci

When I start a new pipeline, I don't want to repeat make the directory build/. But the gitlab-runner always remove the build/. How can i keep the build/ ?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Use a cache: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/

From the docs:

> Use cache for dependencies, like packages you download from the internet. Cache is stored where GitLab Runner is installed and uploaded to S3 if distributed cache is enabled.